# Access key from object that is being created

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like:

```
var foo = {
   a: {
      b: ... || ... || ... || 30
   }
 , c: bar(... || ... || ... || 30)
};
```

Is it possible to access `foo.a.b` key instead of writing again `... || ... || ... || 30` in the `bar` call?

I also can do:

```
foo.c = bar(foo.a.b);
```

But I would choose a shorter way if possible.

I tried to do `bar(this.a.b)` that doesn't work (`Cannot read property 'b' of undefined.`).

Comment: error message? you're at 14.5k rep, don't you know to post what went wrong instead of "that doesn't work"?

Comment: Nop, `this` depends on how the function that uses it gets called; no function there.

Comment: @djechlin The error message is `Cannot read property 'b' of undefined`. I thought it can be simply guesssed. :-)

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, this is not in a function block...

Comment: Sure, but that error message exactly tells you the problem is not where you think it is. You brushed it aside as unimportant (given away by your not posting it); however it was crucial. If you didn't understand the message better to google it.

Comment: As an alternative I suggest `var v = ... || ... || ... 30; var foo = {a: {b: v}, c: bar(v)};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Your error means `this.a` is `undefined`, just like `{}.foo` would be `undefined`, and `{}.foo.bar` would throw an error like `undefined.bar` would throw an error. You can try all this in a console (browser or Node.js).

`this` will bind to the object in a member function (in a pseudo-class), but usually to the global object. (The rules are complicated - please learn them). Without seeing your full code I can't tell, but it really looks like `this` will not refer to `foo`.

Comment: So, isn't there  any way to access a key of an object that is being created? The code is in the global scope.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I see why this is tricky now. Not really; but someone found your correct duplicate.